# Why does my app crash on Blackberry 10 simulator upon input focus?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, phonegap-build

I have an app made using Phonegap, built using Phonegap build into an APK, I converted it into a BAR (repackaged and signed) and installed on a BB10 simulator. I am using Jquery Mobile.

When I tap on an input field (type text, email, password) the app crashes. I initially thought it could be due to some box-shadow CSS but after some testing I determined this is not the cause. I tried this on a BB Playbook device, it does not crash.

I've simplified the code to be very simple, a single page with just a couple input fields.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before? Is it a simulator issue only, and will work fine on an actual device? Is it due to some JS code?

Thanks

Comment: It must be due to JS code as the simulator is the one place where you do not have any bound of hardware.
Does it work fine on android devices?
Please upload the code to JSFiddle or somewhere so that one can review the code and determine the problem.